# MSAL library doesn't open a login window

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, msal

I am writing a wpf application that uses Microsoft Graph Api to access and manage onedrive files.
I am able to login as a user with previous access token that is stored in the cache but when there isn't any token in the cache I want to fetch the access token interactively so I'm using AcquireTokenInteractive but it doesn't open a login window.

I have tried the following things:

1. Checking permission (My application have all the necessary permissions).
2. Checking Redirect URI

This is the code

```
public class MSGraphHelper
{
    private GraphServiceClient graphClient;
    private static readonly string clientId = typeof(Credentials).GetField("OneDriveAppId").GetValue(null).ToString();
    private static readonly string[] scopes = (string[])typeof(Credentials).GetField("OneDriveScopes").GetValue(null);
    private static readonly string tenantId = "common";
    private static readonly string redirectUri = "http://localhost";
    private string accessToken;
    private IPublicClientApplication msalClient;

    // Constructors
    public MSGraphHelper() { }
    public MSGraphHelper(string userName)
    {
        Authenticate(userName);
    }

    private async Task Authenticate(string userName)
    {
        msalClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithRedirectUri(redirectUri).Build();

        TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(msalClient.UserTokenCache, userName);

        var accounts = await msalClient.GetAccountsAsync();
        AuthenticationResult result;
        try
        {
            result = await msalClient.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).WithTenantId(tenantId).ExecuteAsync();
            accessToken = result.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            try
            {
                result = await msalClient.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true).WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}").WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount).ExecuteAsync();
                accessToken = result.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new CustomAuthenticationProvider(accessToken));
        }


    }
    
    // Inner class for authentication
    private class CustomAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
    {
        private string accessToken;
        public CustomAuthenticationProvider(string accessToken)
        {
            this.accessToken = accessToken;
        }

        public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        }

        public Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(RequestInformation request, Dictionary<string, object>? additionalAuthenticationContext = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    // Method to get the graphClient
    public GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient()
    {
        return graphClient;
    }
}
```